# $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{a_n}{b_n})= 0 $ with $a_n $ as a zero sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a  $\mathbb R$ zero sequence. Also, let $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a sequence with $b_n\neq0 $   $\forall n\in \mathbb N$ and where $0$ is no accumulation point. Show that:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{a_n}{b_n})= 0 $

This seems intuitively right to me, but I am having trouble finding a starting point from where I could develop a formalised proof. Maybe someone can give some (general) guidance on how to approach this problem. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $0$ is not an accumulation point of $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and since $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):b_n\neq0$, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):|b_n|\geqslant\varepsilon$.